# How do I pause Starseed Pilgrim?

Tags: starseed-pilgrim

I like being able to pause single-player games like this for when I just want to casually play a game and not worry about keeping constant focus on it. Is there a way to pause Starseed Pilgrim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no pause button.

**Source 1** - The game's Steam discussion forum, where a [search for the word pause](http://steamcommunity.com/app/230980/discussions/search/?q=pause) returns a short list of people asking for a pause button.

**Source 2** - [This (kinda spoilery) article](http://www.electrondance.com/faith-of-the-pilgrim/) which mentions: "No pause key becomes a critical issue when working through challenges. The penalty for being distracted with the real world is to lose 10-15 minutes of work."

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to accomplish this by using the OS suspend feature. I wrote an Autohotkey script for this:

```
#p::
{
    ID := WinGetID("A")
    PID := WinGetPID("ahk_id " ID)
    Title := WinGetTitle("ahk_id " ID)
    SuspendedProcess := DllCall("OpenProcess", "uint", 0x1F0FFF, "int", 0, "int", PID)
    DllCall("ntdll.dll\NtSuspendProcess", "ptr", SuspendedProcess)
    MsgBox "Paused", Title
    DllCall("ntdll.dll\NtResumeProcess", "ptr", SuspendedProcess)
    DllCall("CloseHandle", "ptr", SuspendedProcess)
    WinActivate "ahk_id " ID
}
```

That'll suspend the game's process when you press win+P (key combination can be changed by editing "#p::" at the start, see https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols). Then you can dismiss the dialog box to resume.

This is an OS feature that's not really "supposed" to be used this way, the main thing I noticed is that Windows will consider it to be "not responding" while suspended (because it isn't), and it may not allow you to see or focus the window. Attempts to do that may also prompt you to kill the process. (This is why a dialog box is required, and it can't be a simple button toggle as my first attempt did.)